# Cometí un error en un UPDATE sin WHERE en SQL, ¿Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estimadxs, buen día, cometí un error en un `SP` en `SQLSERVER` en el cual debía actualizar un campo de la siguiente manera:

> Si el campo es nulo, se convertía en un espacio vacío
> Si el campo no era nulo, se hacía lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE TABLA
SET campo = ISNULL(campo , '') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + (SELECT ISNULL(campo , '') FROM Tabla WHERE DNI = @dni_viejo) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
```

Como se ve, cometí el tremendo error de no agregar la cláusula `WHERE` luego del `SET` por lo que todos mis registros nulos pasaron a convertirse en espacios en blanco con saltos de línea. Esos espacios en blanco ysaltos de línea se fueron sumando cada vez más y al día de hoy, ese registro puede tener **100/200/300/400** espacios en blanco consaltos de línea. Estuve varios días hasta que pude encontrar el error y bueno, el `UPDATE` quedó así:

```
UPDATE TABLA
SET campo = ISNULL(campo , '') + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + (SELECT ISNULL(campo , '') FROM Tabla WHERE DNI = @dni_viejo) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
WHERE DNI = @dni_nuevo --línea que no contemplé
```

Un `SELECT` demostrativo sería:

```
SELECT campo FROM Tabla WHERE DNI IN (12345678, 87654321)

                                                       --300 espacios en blanco y saltos de línea en dni 12345678
El nuevo dni es: 987654321                                 -- al finalizar el dni, se añadieron también esos múltiples espacios en blanco y saltos de línea en dni 87654321
```

Solucionado eso, como mencioné, tengo muchos registros conformados por sólo muchos espacios en blanco y saltos de línea, ¿Cómo puedo corregir eso para que todos los registros que tengan espacios en blanco y saltos de línea vuelvan a estar en nulos (primer dni), y que todos aquellos que no son nulos pero tengan muchos espacios en blanco y saltos de línea ya no los tengan (segundo dni)?

Para pasar a null a todos aquellos registros que solo posean espacios en blanco y/o saltos de líneas, hice lo siguiente:

```
UPDATE Tabla
SET campo = null 
WHERE campo NOT LIKE '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

Mi problema, imparte más del lado de aquellos registros que son como:

```
SELECT campo FROM Tabla WHER DNI = 9876543

Hola pedro   saludos         desde                  argentina ( después de argentina vienen saltos de línea x100)
```

Ese registro trae muchos espacios en blanco y/o muchos saltos de línea
Me conformo con solo eliminar los últimos saltos de línea después de la última letra o punto en el registro. Para ello pensé algo como esto:

```
declare @a as varchar(max) = (select memoadmin from Temp where dni = 2023702)

select RIGHT(@a, CHARINDEX('%[a-zA-Z0-9.]%', REVERSE(@a)) -1)
```

Pero, eso me trae el siguiente error:

```
Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function.
```

**

### ACTUALIZACÓN:

**

Una posible solución sería la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @m AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT campo FROM Tabla WHERE dni = 123456789)
PRINT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@m), CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@m)), LEN(@m)))
```

En esta opción, funcionaría. El problema es que si el último carácter no es un punto, se borraría todo lo que viene después. Por ejemplo:

```
Hola 
pepito.
Saludos 
salto de línea x100
```

Quedaría:

```
Hola 
pepito.
```

Ahora, si lo que quiero es buscar que el último carácter sea una letra o un número o un punto:

```
PRINT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@m), CHARINDEX('%[a-zA-Z09.]%', REVERSE(@m)), LEN(@m)))
```

El resultado es:

```
Hola 
pepito.
Saludos 
salto de línea x100
```

Por lo que esta última opción no soluciona el problema

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que realizar update comprobando estas dos condiciones (espacios en blanco y saltos de línea), lo puedes hacer de forma individual o ambos al mismo tiempo.

De forma individual sería asi:

Para espacios en blanco:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo = NULL
WHERE TRIM(campo) = '';
```

Para saltos de línea:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo = NULL
WHERE campo LIKE '%\n%';
```

Ambas al mismo tiempo sería asi:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo = NULL
WHERE TRIM(campo) = '' OR campo LIKE '%\n%';
```

... este último dependiendo de tu motor de base de datos lo puedes hacer de la siguiente forma si no te funciona el anterior:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo = NULL
WHERE TRIM(campo) = '' OR campo LIKE CONCAT('%', CHAR(10), '%');
```

Según tu último comentario te agregue el siguiente UPDATE:

```
UPDATE tabla
SET campo = REPLACE(REPLACE(campo, '\r\n', ''), '  ', ' ')
WHERE campo LIKE '%\r\n%' OR campo LIKE '%  %';
```

Comment: Vale, eso si. Lo he hecho de esta forma:  `update Tabla
set campo = null where campo not like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'` mi problema va con los registros que son  (por ejemplo ) `campo = hola 123 (salto de linea) pedro (salto de linea x100)`

Comment: No, eso no ha solucionado el inconveniente (tu última actualización). Sigue manteniendo los n salto de líneas/espacios